# Add hyperlink to a text python

Tags: python, href

hello i've a link and a text . i wanted to hyperlink this text.

for example:

i tried the below one. but its not adding the new_text link in the hyperlink_format.

```
new_test='www.youtube.com/'
hyperlink_format= '<a href=new_test>text of the link</a>'
```

Output i'm getting when printing `hyperlink_format`

`<a href=new_test>text of the link</a>`

my use_case is it should print the

`'<a href=www.youtube.com/>text of the link</a>'`

i've also tried with `<a href='{}{}'>{}'.format()' but this requires two parameters, so cannot go ahead with this? anyother thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: You DO have two parameters: URL and text   `"<a href='{}'>{}</a>".format("www.youtube.com","text of the link")`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want to insert link to `<a>` tag use `f'<a href="https://{new_test}">text of the link</a>'`

Comment: no the link which i'm giving changes everytime so it should not be dynamic

Comment: You mean "it SHOULD be dynamic".

Answer (score 0):

For the first method, you should embrace the argument in curly brackets, like `<a href={new_test}>text of the link</a>`. And for the second method, you haven't provided the arguments to the format, it should be like this: `<a href={}>text</a>'.format(new_test)`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i've figured it out.

i was able to get this by format.

`hyperlink_format= "<a href='{}'>{}</a>".format(text,"text of the link")`

the miss was `'<a href=\'{}{}\'>{}</a>'` i'm giving two parathesis and format expecting two so i've given one which made me to get the ouput.

Anyway thanks for the suggestions.